# Adding variable to JavaScript drop down list

Tags: javascript

I have a navigation bar that I lists what a CSR can see in the administration part of the site. As the administration is being opened up to vendors I want to restrict what they can see.

```
 stES();
 stIT("p0i3",["Shows"],"p0i2");
 stBS("p2",[],"p1");
 stIT("p2i0",["View Shows","list1.cfm?mode=vs" ],"p1i0");
 stIT("p2i1",["Edit Shows","list.cfm" ],"p1i0");
 stIT("p2i2",["Add Show","add.cfm" ],"p1i0");
 stIT("p2i3",["View Show Services","list1.cfm?mode=vss" ],"p1i0");
 stIT("p2i4",["Edit Show Services","list2.cfm?mode=ess" ],"p1i0");
 stIT("p2i5",["Edit Show Order Text","list1.cfm?mode=est" ],"p1i0");
```

etc.

The calling page has a variable that I want in the url of the list so that a link like:

```
 list1.cfm?mode=vs"
```

would look like:

```
 list1.cfm?mode=vs&myvariable=1
```

Is there a simple dynamic way to add so different vendors have only access assigned to them?

This is strictly a JavaScript issue as I can see it. The page is .js.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Do you mean that you would like to show different options in the drop down list based on the query string?

Comment: Yes. depending on who signs in I want to give them specific permissions only such as r123 which would describe the venue and event they are assigned to.

Comment: Are you using any of the javascript frameworks or using just native javascript? I can barely understand the purpose of your sample code. Suggest to edit the question and explain more precisely. What technique are you using to identify the user? Simply query string? Cookies?Others?

Comment: This is just part of an expandable menu. What I want to achieve is the ability to add a variable to links(s) as menu is created. Nothing more, nothing less.